# Android JSON Parsing images into imageview with cached thumbnails

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to develop an app which works by parsing json and adding parsed json into `Imageview`. I set a `GridView` and `Imageview` into it as a row. When I run app, pictures get parsed as well but when I scroll down, the thumbnails get lost.

The video at this URL [Json thumbs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NpnWEPqIa4U) shows what I mean.

Here my MainActivity.java:

```
package berkantkz.wallstation;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.baoyz.widget.PullRefreshLayout;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<Actors> actorsList;
    ActorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar tool_bar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        tool_bar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        tool_bar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        actorsList = new ArrayList<Actors>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/berkantkz/misc/master/sample.json");


        PullRefreshLayout layout = (PullRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        // listen refresh event
        layout.setRefreshStyle(PullRefreshLayout.STYLE_MATERIAL);
        layout.setOnRefreshListener(new PullRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // start refresh
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);  //your class
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

        // refresh complete
        layout.setRefreshing(false);


        final GridView listview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ActorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, actorsList);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int position, long id) {
                //
                final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
                toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
                linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                //tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
                Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                        .load(actorsList.get(position).getImage())
                        .into(iv, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }
                });
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        GridView listview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.default_bg));
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("actors");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Actors actor = new Actors();
                        actor.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                        actorsList.add(actor);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.refresh) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Actors.java

```
package berkantkz.wallstation;

/**
 * Created by berka on 1.12.2016.
 */
public class Actors {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String image;
    public Actors() {

    }

    //Getters and setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

ActorAdapter.java

```
package berkantkz.wallstation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by berka on 25.11.2016.
 */
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
    ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        actorList = objects;
        Log.d("Deneme", "birinci");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("Deneme", "iki");
        // convert view = design
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            //holder.tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            //holder.tvDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.transparent);
        new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
        //holder.tvName.setText(actorList.get(position).getName());
        //holder.tvDescription.setText(actorList.get(position).getDescription());
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageview;
        //public TextView tvName;
        //public TextView tvDescription;

    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `DownloadImageTask`?? Why? You clearly have Picasso in your Activity

Comment: DownlaodImageTask only downloads images as Thumbnail as you can see on video. And Picasso does, shows full screen image into a ImageView onClick. DownloadImageTask doesn't cache the images. I want that it to cache.

Comment: If you want it to cache, then use Picasso for all images

Comment: Omg I couldn't thought that before. I'll try. Thanks!